# Calculating an Integral by Integration by parts

Tags: integration

I'm stuck on solving this integral:

$\int_1^\infty x^ne^{1-x}dx$

Specifically, I tried to calculate some values for $n=2$ or $n=3$, but I end up with the wrong solutions. Maybe you guys can take a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's been a while since I worked with integrals.

So, for $n=2$, we have:

$\int_1^\infty x^2e^{1-x}dx =[-x²e^{1-x}]_1^\infty -2\int_1^\infty xe^{1-x}$

Now:

$[-x²e^{1-x}]_1^\infty=1$

So:

$1-2\int_1^\infty xe^{1-x}=1-2([-xe^{1-x}]_1^\infty-\int_1^\infty e^{1-x})$

$=> 1-2(1-1) = 1$

The answer should be $5$, where did I make a mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you integrate by parts, the last integral is a minus. But you also forgot to tack on the minus from integrating the $e^{1-x}$ term, so it should be plus.

Comment: You forgot a minus sign in the first line! There is the minus sign of $[-x^{2}e^{1-x}]$ and the minus sine from integration by parts.

Comment: I would suggest you to watch this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I-_SV8cwsw) where the DI method on integration by parts is explained. It is a faster and more elegant method for dealing with integration by parts but it is based on the same idea. I think that you will find it useful for future work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a negative sign on the second integral.

$$\int_1^\infty x^2e^{1-x}dx =[-x²e^{1-x}]_1^\infty -2\int_1^\infty xe^{1-x}$$ should have been $$\int_1^\infty x^2e^{1-x}dx =[-x²e^{1-x}]_1^\infty + 2\int_1^\infty xe^{1-x}$$

Answer (score 3):

For the general case, this is better approached through $u$-substitution using the fact that $\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx = n!$:
\begin{multline}
\int_1^\infty x^ne^{1-x}dx = \int_0^\infty (u+1)^ne^{-u}du = \int_0^\infty\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} u^{n-k}\right]e^{-u}du\\=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\int_0^\infty u^{n-k}e^{-u}du = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}.
\end{multline}

This sum is easy to evaluate for small $n$. $n=2$ gives $ 2 + 2 + 1 = 5$ and $n=3$ gives $6 + 6 + 3+ 1 = 16$, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

For doing the general $n$ case, use the substitution $u=x-1$ to get the integral

$$\int_0^\infty (u+1)^n e^{-u}du$$

Then use binomial expansion

$$ = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} u^ke^{-u}du = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \int_0^\infty u^ke^{-u}du = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} k!$$

where we use the handy fact that

$$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx = n!$$

which was the intuition basis for doing our change of variable.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't answer the question asked, but gives an alternative approach:

Let $I(t) = \int_1^\infty e^{-xt} dx$. Note that $I(t) = e^{-t} {1 \over t}$ and 
$I^{(n)}(t) =(-1)^n \int_1^\infty x^ne^{-xt} dx$,
so $\int_1^\infty x^ne^{1-x} dx = (-1)^ne I^{(n)}(1) $.

All that remains is to compute $I^{(n)}(t)$.

I claim that $I^{(n)}(t) = (-1)^ne^{-t} \sum_{k=0}^n {n! \over k!} t^{k-n-1}$. It is straightforward to see that this holds for $n=0$, so suppose it is true for $n$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
I^{(n+1)}(t) &=& {d \over dt} I^{(n)}(t) \\
&=& (-1)^ne^{-t} \sum_{k=0}^n  {n! \over k!} (-t^{k-n-1} - (n-(k-1)) t^{(k-1)-n-1}) \\
&=& (-1)^{n+1}e^{-t}({n! \over n!} t^{-1}+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  {n! \over k!} t^{k-n-1} +
\sum_{k=1}^n  {n! \over k!} (n-(k-1)) t^{(k-1)-n-1} + (n+1){n! \over 0!} t^{-n-2}) \\
&=& (-1)^{n+1}e^{-t}({n! \over n!} t^{-1}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}  {n! \over (k-1)!} t^{(k-1)-n-1} +
\sum_{k=1}^n  {n! \over k!} (n-(k-1)) t^{(k-1)-n-1} + {(n+1)! \over 0!} t^{-n-2}) \\
&=& (-1)^{n+1}e^{-t}({n! \over n!} t^{-1}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( {n! \over (k-1)!}  +
 {n! \over k!} (n-(k-1)) )t^{(k-1)-n-1} + {(n+1)! \over 0!} t^{-n-2}) \\
&=& (-1)^{n+1}e^{-t}({(n+1)! \over (n+1)!} t^{-1}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n} {(n+1)! \over k!} t^{k-(n+1)-1} + {(n+1)! \over 0!} t^{-n-2}) \\
&=& (-1)^{n+1}e^{-t} \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {(n+1)! \over k!} t^{k-(n+1)-1}
\end{eqnarray}